# Oracle SQL: Concern About Barred Relationships

Tags: sql, oracle

I have recently learned about “barred relationships” when developing an ERD through the Oracle Academy service. The course gave the following definition of a barred relationship: “A relationship that participates in an entity’s unique identifier” I understand how this works in the context of resolving a M:M relationship by creating an intersection entity and having the UID of that entity come from the originating relationships. My question is: Can a barred relationship occur in an instance where there is no intersection entity, or are barred relationships reserved for intersection entities?

Comment: Perhaps this will help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27891738/barred-relationship-oracle-academy.  I think "barred" in this context refers to how the relationship is displayed rather than meaning "forbidden".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Barred, that is, bar-ed ids are literally the original ids of the two entities connected by the relation with a bar (pipe, `|`) in between. Like in a CSV file.

The term is unusual and an invention of that course, I would say. It certainly is not usually used in the generic SQL world, nor even in the Oracle RDBMS documentation.